# How to simulate two counters using one (FIFO) queue?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, turing-machines

How to simulate two counters using one (FIFO) queue? (In terms of algorithms, unary stack.)

Comment: did you mean to ask whether you can simulate two FIFO stacks using only one?

Comment: We discourage questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Please define your terms. What would it mean to simulate two counters using one queue?

Comment: This question is incorrect. A stack is LIFO

Answer (score 1):

[Queue automata are Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_automaton#Turing_completeness), so they can simulate any machine, including a two-counter machine.